# Postgres- update a value in a array on particular index

Tags: postgresql, update, array

I have a column named `ids` that is of type `bigint[]`. ids can be null or of any length

It has values based on certain hierarchy.

My use case is I want to update value that is at a particular index.
For example `ids[2] = 50`.

How can I achieve this?

I looked at [PostgreSQL documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)
but couldn't find anything that could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed there is no such function, but you can easily write your own:

```
create function array_set(p_input anyarray, p_index int, p_new_value anyelement)
  returns anyarray
as
$$
begin
  if p_input is not null then
    p_input[p_index] := p_new_value;
  end if;
  return p_input;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
immutable;
```

(If you never need it for anything different than `bigint[]` then you can replace the `anyelement` and `anyarray` with the equivalent types)

Then you can use it like this:

```
update the_table
  set ids = array_set(ids, 2, 50::bigint)
where ...;
```

Comment: Thank you :) That's a pretty elegant approach.

Comment: When used in a function, that approach is more efficient than my answer.

Comment: There is no need to create function for that, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `unnest` to make a table from the array and `array_agg` to aggregate it back into an array.

To replace the third element in an array of `integer` with 42, you could for example use

```
SELECT array_agg(
          CASE WHEN num = 3
               THEN 42
               ELSE elem
          END
          ORDER BY num
       )
FROM unnest('{1,2,4,5}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(elem, num);

 array_agg  
------------
 {1,2,42,5}
(1 row)
```

You could write your own function based on that.

`WITH ORDINALITY` tracks the ordering of the array elements, so that you can identify the currect one, and `ORDER BY` makes sure that the final aggregate constructs the array in the same order.

Comment: Thank you so much :). This works.
But I wanted to confirm will it change the actual position of the array elements?
and how does just  ```ELSE unnest``` work? Because unnest doesnot have any parameter here.

Comment: Sorry, that's confusing. `ordinality` and `unnest` are the column names that PostgreSQL chooses by default. I have modified the answer to use an explicit alias - maybe that makes things clearer.

Answer (score 2):

```
create temporary table the_table (
    ids bigint[]
);

insert into the_table (ids) values
    (null),
    (array[1, 2]),
    (array[1, 2, 3]);

update the_table
set ids[2] = 50
where 
  ids is not null and
  array_upper(ids, 1) >= 2;
  
select * from the_table;
```

[image]

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-MODIFYING